# Tensorflow C++ fast Tensor deep copy

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am writing a custom tensorflow op in C++ and I want to know how I might perform a deep copy of one tensor into another.  In other words, I want an element-wise copy from one tensor to another such that they are not made to share an underlying memory buffer.

The closest thing I've found is DeepCopy (defined in [tensor_util.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/53e3c4f7070c47c7f0bb72732abb0f3b2dff1977/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_util.h#L37)).  The problem is I need this operation to be fast and the documentation states clearly that this function has not been optimized for speed:

```
// DeepCopy returns a tensor whose contents are a deep copy of the
// contents of 'other'.  This function is intended only for
// convenience, not speed.
```

A bit more detail: I am using Tensorflow on the GPU, so basically what I want to do is to have TF initiate a cudaMemcpy where both source and target are device pointers.  TF does give access to tensor pointers (tensor.tensor_data().data()), but you run into problems pretty quick if you try to cudaMemcpy with them (they have to do with overlapping cuda contexts; not nice).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the exceptions I was getting when I tried a manual cudaMalloc were due to an orthogonal issue.  Once solved, it works, though I am a little leery of mucking around with TF's internals in this way.

Comment: Can you provide any sample code of your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently for "fast" deep copies, TensorFlow uses Eigen to implement CPU and GPU versions. Being Eigen, the code is deeply templated, but the relevant code is here (copied from [`dense_update_ops.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d23960e29c3efb1b30c5cb6f8f3368635b97f29/tensorflow/core/kernels/dense_update_ops.h#L48)):

```
template <typename Device, typename T>
struct DenseUpdate<Device, T, ASSIGN> {
  void operator()(const Device& d, typename TTypes<T>::Flat params,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstFlat update) {
    params.device(d) = update;
  }
};
```